# Drawing a sourcerectangle from a spritesheet doesn't seem to work (Monogame)

Tags: c#, monogame

## Solved

I'm working with monogame to make a basic 2D platformer. So far haven't had many problems, drawing the entire spritesheet was no problem.

I wanted to add the running animation, knowing each sprite is 41 pixels wide and 54 pixels high I passed a source rectangle of those dimensions with the correct position to the draw function. For some reason it now does not draw anything anymore.

This is my original Draw function that did work:

```cs
public virtual void Draw()
{
    if(sprite != null)
    {
        Globals.spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, new Rectangle((int)pos.X, (int)pos.Y, (int)dims.X, (int)dims.Y), null, Color.White, 0.0f, new Vector2(sprite.Bounds.Width / 2, sprite.Bounds.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
}
```

And this is the one with a source rectangle that doesn't work:

```cs
public virtual void Draw(Rectangle frame)
{
    if (sprite != null)
    {
        Globals.spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, new Rectangle((int)pos.X, (int)pos.Y, (int)dims.X, (int)dims.Y), frame, Color.White, 0.0f, new Vector2(sprite.Bounds.Width / 2, sprite.Bounds.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
}
```

It's called by a overwritten draw function in the player class:

```cs
public override void Draw()
{
    base.Draw(new Rectangle(frame * 41, 0, 41, 54));
}
```

The `frame` variable is updated each frame with this formula:

```cs
frame = (frame + 1) % 4;
```

Comment: Are you sure `frame` in your overridden `Draw` method is actually within bounds? It should have a value from 0 to animationLength - 1 or such.

Comment: ``frame`` is a value between 0 and 4, my spritesheet is much longer than that so I think that shouldn't be the problem here. I've already debugged and the value does stay nicely within it's bounds at all times.

Comment: Can you try passing `new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)dims.X, (int)dims.Y)` instead of frame? Does it draw the first frame of the animation? (assuming `dims` are the dimensions of the sprite, not the texture - if not, change that, or you're drawing way too much). I find it hard to believe there's an error in the code you posted. Make sure `sprite` is what you expect it to be, and the same for all the bounds.

Comment: I still had ``dims`` as the texture dimensions, thank you. This completely solved it.

Comment: If this has solved your question, then you may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to update the dimensions of the rectangle. It had nothing to do with the source rectangle itself.